# Ruby On Rails iterator .each block error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, block, each

i have an exception caught with this code and i can't pinpoint the error.

```
  def paypal_content
    payment = {}
    payment[:intent] = "sale"
    payment[:payer] = { :payment_method => "paypal" }
    payment[:redirect_urls] = { :return_url => "http://localhost:3000/payment/execute", :cancel_url => "http://localhost:3000"}

    items = []
    index = 0
    @cart.items.each do |item|
       items[index] = {}
       items[index][:name] = item.title
       items[index][:sku] = item.artist
       items[index][:price] = item.price.to_s
       items[index][:quantity] = "1"
       items[index][:currency] = "CHF"
       index++      
    end  <--- this is line 109

    item_list = {}
    item_list[:items] = items

    transactions = []
    transactions[0] = {}
    transactions[0][:item_list] = item_list
    transactions[0][:amount] = { :total => @cart.total_price.to_s, :currency => "CHF"}
    transactions[0][:description] = "from Larraby Blaine Esquire"

    payment[:transactions] = transactions

    return payment
  end
```

the error is 
home_controller.rb:109  syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
home_controller.rb:125: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

If i remove the each block everithing is fine, so i guess i made a mistake with the block but what mistake ??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby does not know `++`, write `+= 1`.

When you write `index++`, it thinks the first `+` is addition, and the second `+` a unary sign. You can't have a sign without something after it, so it expects an expression, but finds `end`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution and explanation. i was going crazy about that. i knew it was something stupidly simple, i'm pretty sure now that i will never do that ++ mistake again thanks to your explanation